# Linq opening and closing parentheses does not match

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, linq, linq-to-entities

I have this code:

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
            {
              refer =  db.Refferals.Where(r =>
                r.RefferalDetails.Any(rd =>
                (Name.Contains(rd.Name) || rd.Name.Contains(Name) || LastName.Contains(rd.LastName) || rd.LastName.Contains(LastName) 
                || Company.Contains(r.Company) || r.Company.Contains(Company)
                Mobile.Contains(rd.Mobile) || rd.Mobile.Contains(Mobile))) &&
                Mobile.Length > 9 && Name.Length > 1 && LastName.Length > 1 && Company.Length > 2
                ).ToArray();

            }
```

Although the parentheses count is correct but the editor offers that there is one extra parantheses. 
    [image]

I tried restarting Visual Studio but its the same.

Comment: That looks everything other than matching !

Comment: You've got no operator between `r.Company.Contains(Company)` and `Mobile.Contains(rd.Mobile)`. More generally, though, this is entirely unreadable - it's very hard to see what's wrong.

Comment: well where is the problem? you say that opening and closing parentheses does not match?

Comment: What's the closing parenthesis before `.ToArray()` supposed to match to?

Comment: @CharlesMager Thanks a lottttt. Me and my brother are looking at it for half an hour and couldn't see that. It solved the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the missing `||` between `r.Company.Contains(Company)` and `Mobile.Contains(rd.Mobile)`.

And fix the indenting, that makes it much easier to see what's wrong. When I indented it, the missing operator stuck out like a sore thumb, and it's easy to see how the parens work.

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
{
    refer = db.Refferals.Where(r =>
        r.RefferalDetails.Any(rd => 
            (
                Name.Contains(rd.Name) 
                || rd.Name.Contains(Name) 
                || LastName.Contains(rd.LastName) 
                || rd.LastName.Contains(LastName)
                || Company.Contains(r.Company) 
                || r.Company.Contains(Company)

                || /* <-- ADDED OR OPERATOR HERE */
                   Mobile.Contains(rd.Mobile) 

                || rd.Mobile.Contains(Mobile)
            )
        ) 
        && Mobile.Length > 9 
        && Name.Length > 1 
        && LastName.Length > 1 
        && Company.Length > 2
    ).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's missing one**||** before Mobile.Contains(rd.Mobile)

```
refer = db.Refferals.Where
                (
                    r => r.RefferalDetails.Any
                    (
                        rd =>
                            (
                                Name.Contains(rd.Name) || rd.Name.Contains(Name) || LastName.Contains(rd.LastName) || rd.LastName.Contains(LastName)
                                    || Company.Contains(r.Company) || r.Company.Contains(Company)
                                            || Mobile.Contains(rd.Mobile) || rd.Mobile.Contains(Mobile)
                             )
                    )
                    && Mobile.Length > 9 && Name.Length > 1 && LastName.Length > 1 && Company.Length > 2
                ).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without running code it seems you do some kind of unary selections (rd). I would suggest you start refactoring your code and break out each condition a part...